# How to do a condition if into the select linq?

Tags: .net, linq

I have sql parameter :

```
SqlParameter[] parameters2 =
{

    new SqlParameter("@codes_PrestaOOP", 
                     string.Concat(contactUS.Select(s => $"{s.PK_PrestaOOP},")))
};
```

And I want to concatenate @codes_PrestaOOP only if `@codes_PrestaOOP != null`.

How do it ?

Comment: You mean if `contactUS` is not null, or the items in it?

Comment: Not contactUS is not null but PK_PrestaOOP. I want do it in the same line and I dont know a syntax of linq. Like that? : contactUS.Select(s => $"{s.(if (PK_PrestaOOP != null) } ?

Comment: Use a `Where()`: `contactUS.Where(s => s.PK_PrestaOOP != null).Select(...`

Comment: If you wanted to know where `PK_PrestaOOP` is not null why did you write `@codes_PrestaOOP != null`

Comment: Thanks you a lot

Comment: Magnus :  because I don't know linq.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `Where`.

```
 SqlParameter[] parameters2 =
    {
        new SqlParameter("@codes_PrestaOOP", 
                         string.Concat(contactUS.Where(s => s.PK_PrestaOOP != null)
                                                .Select(s => $"{s.PK_PrestaOOP},")))
    };
```

Comment: Thanks you a lot, I'm a beginner